# Training Dialogflow Agent using Python SDK

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, agent

i using dialogflow v2 with python sdk.

All works fine, except when i add a new intent with its training phrases. The bot doesnt recognize the phrases until i enter through the web console and save the intent, when the training start, after that, the bot works well.

[image: Saving the intent from web]

I tried to train the intent using the python sdk:

```
agent_client = dialogflow.AgentsClient(credentials=self.credentials)
response = agent_client.train_agent('projects/' + self.project_id)
```

The response is 200, but the agent wasnt trained.

Thanks to any clue how to make this work.

Comment: How did you determine that the response was 200?

Comment: In the *respones* object.

Comment: I'm asking because the SDKs methods are asynchronous, `train_agent` returns a future which does not initially contain any information about the result of the training operation.

Answer (score 1):

May be, it helps:

```
def train_agent(project_id):
    from google.cloud import dialogflow

    agents_client = dialogflow.AgentsClient()
    parent = dialogflow.AgentsClient.common_project_path(project_id)
    response = agents_client.train_agent(
        request={"parent": parent}
    )

    print(response.done())
```

P.S.: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in my `.env`

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me. Currently, I'm using FastApi. The secret is to add the function done(). That would return true or false if the operation finished successfully.**

```
@router.post("/chatbot/train/{project_id}", response_model=IGetResponseBase)
async def train_agent(
    project_id: str, 
) -> Any:

# Create a client
agent_client = AgentsAsyncClient()
parent = agent_client.common_project_path(project_id)

# Initialize request argument(s)
request = TrainAgentRequest(
    parent=parent,
)

# Make the request
operation = await agent_client.train_agent(request=request)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")


response = await operation.done()

# Handle the response
print('operation', response)
```